# Image sharing in react native application

Tags: android, image, react-native, share

I need to share images that I display in my application by fetching the image url from cloudinary. When I click on share button, it should display the list of application available in my mobile,through which I can share the image.Please suggest me some example links or ideas to implement this in my react native based android application

Comment: check [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I will call the below mentioned **onShare** function on press of share button, it is displaying the share sheet and only the BASE64 url is getting shared not the real image. Please help me share the image

`onShare = () => {
    const content = {
      message:IMAGE_URL_BASE64,
      title: "Share the image",
      url: IMAGE_URL_BASE64
    };
    const option = { dialogTitle: "Share the image" };
    Share.share(content, option);
  };`

Answer (score 0):

- Try to use this "https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share"
- Do follow these configuration steps without fail: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share#Android-Install

Comment: I have tried with this one, but in this case we are hard coding the apps(E;g: Twitter, facebook). We are not getting the list of apps that is available in our mobile. And also getting the following error **Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.application/com.application.MainActivity} does not exist.**

Comment: hey Sri, I believe its due to bundle gradle version and sdk versions if you haven't have installed sdk and bundle versions in your project it will fail to fetch the plugin dependencies, source: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share/issues/323#issuecomment-409180899